# robotframework - select a region on leaflet map

Tags: automated-tests, leaflet, robotframework

I'm testing our web application which has a map inside a form. I use leaflet map to show different regions on it, region ids may change with choosing a combo-box option. I've tried `click element` using Xpath to choose a region but unfortunately it didn't work. Is there any way to select regions from leaflet map with Rrobot Framework?

Below is the Robot Framework code I am using:

```
click element    xpath=.//*[@id='map-id']/div[1]/div[4]/img[89]
```

Here is my form:

[image: Leaflet map]

Comment: Show us what code you used.

Comment: I user this:
click element  xpath=.//*[@id='map-id']/div[1]/div[4]/img[89]

Comment: If this is exactly the code you are using - its missing double space between `element` and `xpath`

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. It says:  Element is not clickable at point ...

Comment: Add wait before it?

Comment: No difference!!

Comment: If you can calculate the coordinates, `click element at coordinates` would be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and there are two ways to fix it: create a custom Python keyword to locate the map element, find the center of the element, calculate a distance away from the center to click, and then click that location (not as hard as it sounds, actually); or click the map element itself (probably by a dom-style locator, those are fairly solid and can click behind transparent overlays) and be happy with the center of the map being the only place you can click it.

Except for the second option, this all assumes that there isn't a transparent overlay blocking Robot Framework from clicking your map, which is something else that could throw that error. If there is, then you may need to go through Javascript via the `Execute Javascript` keyword. Javascript is able to click things behind transparent overlays, assuming the `click ()` command works with your current setup.

If ALL of that fails, you might consider a different custom keyword that moves the cursor and then clicks as the cursor. I don't have access to that code atm, but it's a one-line keyword in Python.

Also, the error might be just because your XPath wasn't specific enough.

Comment: thank u so much. It worked with `click element` and a 3-second sleep after.

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem and was helpful.